# Exception with JavaFX jar

Tags: jar, javafx, include, export

I have export a FX Project as Jar, this exception show me.

http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=4eae98-1432897954.png

http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=aace07-1432898009.png

I have tested an easy FX project without includes without errors.
I believe its about wrong includes path.

Do you have got any idea what i did wrong?

**Update**

Here is the code where the FXML is loaded:

```
public class MatchMaker_Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/matchMakerView/matchMaker_MainScene.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("MatchMaker 3.0@Hades85");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is an link to my include fxml.http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=b463ae-1432898032.png

Comment: Can you add the code where you are loading the fxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name in your code `matchMaker_MainScene.fxml` does not match the name of the file `MatchMaker_MainScene.fxml`.

This will work when you are reading from a file system that doesn't distinguish file names that differ only in case (such as windows) but will not work on file systems that do (everything else) and will not work when the FXML file is bundled in a jar file.

Comment: LoL, OMG. It takes a couple of hours with no result. Shame on me! It works!